# Plotting coordinates in a GeoPandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm trying to plot some coordinates in a map plot with the geopandas library, but I can't get the result I want, it seems that the CRS isn't right but I don't know how to fix it.

I imported the GeoDataframe of the base map as follows:

```
mapa = gpd.read_file('Brasil.json', driver='JSON', crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
```

Link to the json file [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luizpedone/municipal-brazilian-geodata/master/data/Brasil.json).

And the coordinates were transformed into a GeoDataFrame `ubs_coords`:

```
ubs_coords = gpd.GeoDataFrame(coords, geometry='geometry', crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
```

The first 5 elements of `ubs_coords` are:

```
                     coords                                       geometry
0   (-10.911237001418801, -37.062077522276795)  POINT (-10.9112370014188 -37.06207752227679)
1   (-9.48594331741306, -35.8575725555409)      POINT (-9.48594331741306 -35.8575725555409)
2   (-23.896, -53.41)                           POINT (-23.896 -53.41)
3   (-16.447874307632002, -41.0098600387561)    POINT (-16.447874307632 -41.0098600387561)
4   (-6.573311090469169, -35.1076054573049)     POINT (-6.573311090469169 -35.1076054573049)
```

When I run the following code to get the plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = mapa.plot(ax=ax)
ubs_coords.plot(marker='*', markersize=5, ax=ax)
```

I keep getting this:
[link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QCrq.png)

I've already checked the `.crs` and `.geometry` of both GeoDataFrames and both are ok, so I have no clue what is going on here.

Comment: This looks like latitude and longitude have been mixed up in the scatter plot.

Comment: It was exactly this! I inverted the lat/long after seeing your comment and indeed it was mixed up, now i got my map plot! Thank you so much!